# How do I turn off brace highlighing in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In VS 2015 I'm getting a weird brace highlighting effect. Using the Dark theme, I'm getting a light gray box around the pair of braces, parens, or quotation marks when I place the cursor after the closing token.

I though that this was a plugin, but I disabled both CodeRush and Productivity Power Tools and it is still happening.

I thought that VS 2013 did the same thing, but I can't remember how to turn it off.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Tools -> Options
2. Environment -> Fonts and Colors
3. Brace Matching: Set foreground and background to "Automatic".

No need to change Brace Matching (highlight) or Brace Matching (rectangle)

Comment: Thank you so much.  This was driving me crazy!